# nginx A/B test with split client

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

We are trying to use split client module of Nginx for some A/B testing and have found documentation at couple of places

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/
- https://www.viget.com/articles/split-test-traffic-distribution-with-nginx/

So the use case we have is to randomly choose experiment variant based on right now ip and useragent

```
split_clients "${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}" $experiment1 {
            25%    "original";
            25%    "variant1";
            25%    "variant2";
            25%    "variant3";

    }
    
split_clients "${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}" $experiment2 {
            50%    "original";
            50%    "variant1";
    }
```

I am able to use the above value and set into individual proxy headers for multiple locations

```
    location  /x1{
    ...
        proxy_set_header experiment1 $experiment1;
        proxy_set_header experiment1 $experiment2;
    ...
    }
    
    location  /x2{
    ...
        proxy_set_header experiment1 $experiment1;
        proxy_set_header experiment1 $experiment2;
    ...
    }
location  /x3{
    ...
        proxy_set_header experiment1 $experiment1;
    ...
    }
```

This is working fine but my use case is to have the value of the experiment overriden based on existing
What i mean is if I have a header already coming lets say for experiment1, i have to use that as default and not this

```
if ($http_$experiment1) {
  set $experiment1 "$http_$experiment1";
}
```

Also I am looking a way o combined the values of these experiments and put it in a variable dynamically based on location
So if lets say i have a location /x1, I want AB to be

```
proxy_set_header ABExperiment $experiment1=variant1;$experiment2=original
```

whereas for /x3 it will be

```
proxy_set_header ABExperiment $experiment1=variant1;$experiment2=original
```

**What I tried**
For defaulting a value based on existing header as mentioned above I tried putting the following

```
if ($http_$experiment1) {
  set $experiment1 "$http_$experiment1";
}
```

But this does not work globally. I am not allowed to put if after split client or inside split client.

I have to put it inside location tag, which I dont prefer as it should be same for whole location.

Second thing for creating a master data like for which location what experiments should be used and to have it all in one place like a lookup, to get the experiments for a location dynamically I could not find a way like map or something. wherein, i could just fetch the experiment keys for a location and then create a concatenated string of the variants.

sorry if this does not respect stackoverflow policy